# How can I display all of a Customer's contacts under a specific Mailing ID?

Tags: acumatica

In the database, I can't see a direct relation between the BAccount/Customer tables to the Notification/NotificationSource/NotificationRecipient tables. I am trying to find this relationship which I believe is established within Finance -> Accounts Receivable -> Customer -> Mail Settings -> Mailings -> Recipients. I am trying to pull all of a customer's contacts that are active within a specific Mail ID to a page to display for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From BAccount to Contact DAC:

```
[PXParent(typeof(Select<BAccount, 
          Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Current<Contact.bAccountID>>, 
          And<BAccount.type, NotEqual<BAccountType.combinedType>>>>))]
```

From Contact DAC to ContactNotification DAC (**NotificationRecipient.ContactID**):

```
[PXParent(typeof(Select<Contact, 
          Where<Contact.contactID, Equal<Current<ContactNotification.contactID>>>>))]
```

The projection in ContactNotification DAC uses NotificationSource.sourceID Key to retrieve NotificationSource:

```
[PXProjection(typeof(Select2<NotificationRecipient,     
              InnerJoin<NotificationSource,
              On<NotificationSource.sourceID, Equal<NotificationRecipient.sourceID>>>>), 
              Persistent = true)]
```

Comment: How would I use this to set objects in an AddOn project to the data these statements would return when used in a PXSelect statement? I tried to transforming them into PXSelect statements within a function, but received errors. I believe the errors targeted the .Select(this,...) segment of the statement. The error is: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PX.Data.PXSelectBase<PX.Objects.CR.Contact>.Select(params object[])'.

Comment: When extending an existing Acumatica Graph, you would use 'Base' instead of 'this', .Select(Base,...). If you are creating a new graph (not a graph extension) you would use 'this'.

Comment: I don't think you quite understood my situation. I'm using an AddOn project (separate from the base website) and am trying to use PXSelect statements to get data from the database. It's just a plain class that I'm using, so I'm not sure what I need to put within the Select for it to work. Base and this does not work due to it is not an extension nor a customized page.

Comment: To make a call to the Database using the PXSelect function you need a reference to a PXGraph object, it's the first parameter of PXSelect and isn't optional. This reference takes the form of an instance derived from PXGraph or PXGraphExtension. I wouldn't recommend using POCO objects in your extension but if you have too either pass a graph to your object as a reference or instantiate a PXGraph in your object using the PXGraph.CreateInstance<GraphClass>() method.

Comment: I'll just include my code here. This is what I have: Contact con = PXSelect<Contact, Where<Contact.contactID, Equal<Required<BAccount.bAccountID>>>>.Select(this, customerId);. In the .Select(this, customerId), I get an error when using "this". The error is: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PX.Data.PXSelectBase<PX.Objects.CR.Contact>.Select(params object[])'. Am I able to use PXSelect commands in an "AddOn" project, or do I need to use ADO.Net to access the database (which I'd rather not)? If I'm able to, what am I missing so I don't get that error?

Comment: If you're looking to get your extension certified ADO.Net is prohibited, amongst other issues it would bypass Acumatica security mechanisms. To call PXSelect you need a reference to a PXGraph object or an object derived from it. Check the declaration of your class, does it derives from PXGraph or PXGraphExtension? class ClassName : PXGraph<> or class ClassName : PXGraphExtension<> If not, then you have to instantiate a PXGraph object manually, note that this would be an unusual use case as code classes in Extension projects usually derives from PXGraph/PXGraphExtension.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand correctly, what do you mean by "using an AddOn project separate from the base website"? The AddOn project is meant to be dynamically linked with the base website, it won't work as part of another solution that is not running an Acumatica Website. The Website is the entry point that calls into the AddOn project.

Comment: To add to the above comment: I believe I understand what is going on now. The key word "this" is supposed to be referencing a BLC, but because I'm using an AddOn project and blank class, I do not directly reference any BLC. Do I need to somehow link this custom class I'm making to a BLC, or do I need to use something else of Acumatica's operations to fill in required parameters within the PXSelect<>.Select(params[]) statement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137949/discussion-between-ericp-and-hb-acumatica).

Comment: Thank you for the help! The information provided did answer my original question.